# UNIX Script for searching in logs and files and extracting lines

Tags: unix, find

I'm trying to write a script that can search in log files for a specific text and write down the line in a txt file. Log files are archived once every 2 days, so i need to search in archived files also.

Something like:

```
-bash-3.2$ ssh server.com
-bash-3.2$ cd test/log/
less server.log.2012-06-19.gz | grep "text" -> ~/test.txt
```

I'm kind of a newbie in UNIX
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
zgrep text server.log* >~/test.txt
```

Comment: something like, but i need to go through the whole folder, all the logs and all the archives in the folder

Comment: That's what it should do if your logs match the `server.log*` pattern.

Comment: thanks it work so far, altho some log files have 1Gb so its gonna take a while thanks

Comment: You're welcome. And sorry, it wasn't me who created those huge logfiles! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
gzcat <your_gz_file>|grep string >output_file
```